# Windows Phone 8 Arabic Keyboard as Default

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

**I would like to know is it possible to show Arabic key board as default, while user taps on a textbox in my WP8 application?**

Currently its showing English as default. **Also please let me know how to know whether Arabic key board is installed/available in phone?**

Thanks in advance

Regards

Anish

Comment: The default keyboard depends on the users locale. I imagine the emulator defaults to english, but you can reconfigure that.

Comment: thank you codemonkeh, let me know how to change to Arabic when user taps a textbox?

Comment: you can't change it. User is the only person who can change settings.

Comment: is it possible to restrict the text box to accept only Arabic language characters?

Comment: Your best bet is to use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` to find out what is being used, then make a decision (display message, etc) based on that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can set it.
Refer this link for your Answer.

> [Change Keyboard Layout Run Time](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Changing-Keyboard-Layout-d50b27da)

I Hope you will get the Answer.

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.InputLanguage not found in Windows Phone 8 C# XAML API references